# Ruby parse string to json

Tags: json, ruby

So I have some json that looks like this, which I got after taking it out of some other json by doing `response.body.to_json`:

```
{\n \"access_token\": \"<some_access_token>\",\n \"token_type\": \"Bearer\",\n \"expires_in\": 3600,\n \"id_token\": \<some_token>\"\n}\n"
```

I want to pull out the access_token, so I do

```
to_return = {token: responseJson[:access_token]}
```

but this gives me a

> TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

Why? How do I get my access token out? Why are there random backslashes everywhere?

Comment: try this example
`s = "{\n \"access_token\": \"<some_access_token>\",\n \"token_type\": \"Bearer\",\n \"expires_in\": 3600,\n \"id_token\": \"<some_token>\"\n}\n"`,
`res = JSON.parse(s)`,
`res["access_token"]`

Answer (score 3):

`to_json` doesn't parse JSON - it does the complete opposite: it turns a ruby object into a string containing the JSON representation of that object is.

It's not clear from your question what `response.body` is. It could be a string, or depending on your http library it might have already been parsed for you.

If the latter then

```
response.body["access_token"]
```

Will be your token, if the former then try

```
JSON.parse(response.body)["access_token"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use with double quotes when calling access_token. Like below:

```
to_return = {token: responseJson["access_token"]}
```

Or backslashes are escaped delimiters and make sure you first parse JSON.

Comment: didn't I parse the json with my `to_json` call?

Comment: @praks5432 you still parse the json using `to_json`

Comment: @praks5432 but after parsing you have use string ["access_token"] not symbol [:access_token] to access it.

Comment: Parse the JSON and paste the output here. you can use JSON.parse(your_variable).